# Having an hard issues with google and his API or login buttons

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-signin

I followed the documentation from them and i don't see what is my error from my part !

I'm trying to get the information from the profile of the user (which could be the name gender etc etc...)
And i followed all the steps from google website (in my case, the javascript code)

Everything works, less that request which i want to do to the user profile!

This example is the **callback function** after logging to the google account which is automatically executed:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
   if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
   // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
   // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
   //document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
   console.log(authResult);

   gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY'); //(That function gaves me an error which is invalid credentials, i did put my API_KEY (from the google console ))


   gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
      'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
     console.log(resp);
   //console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName);
    });
   });

   gapi.auth.signOut(); // logging out !

  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
```

Everything works less than setAPIkeys and everything below !
If i don't put the set function and the code below, i receive an 400 error ("message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.").

So i'm losing hope in doing that sincerely ... i think that google's documentation is awful !
What's wrong with that?

Merry christmas to everyone !

P.S. : yeah i know that the API key musn't be hard coded, but i'm so lost with the documentation from google sincerely ...

Comment: You don't need to set an API key if you are making requests authenticated as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

---

Try removing

`gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');`

and

`gapi.auth.signOut(); // logging out !`

signOut works very fast, while `gapi.client.load`  is asynchronous function which loads js code. User is probably signed out before `gapi.client.load`  callback is executed.

---

I'm not sure if that's required:

1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
2. Select your project.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth.
4. In the displayed list of APIs, find the Google+ API and set its status to ON.

---

Make sure you're requesting scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me while signing in.

Comment: Reallyyy ???? Just because signet works very fast ? Come one :(
And what about that setApiKey ? For what use is it ? 
Thanks it works now ! :)